# What is a good 64 bit physically small server?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I've got a 5 year old shuttle machine. It's 32 bit, only takes 2gb of ram and is old. I'm looking for a replacement machine that is a similar size, is 64bit and supports at least 8gb RAM.

I'm not looking for a rack mounted system as they are too deep and I don't have a rack at home! Ideally it would be a similar form factor to the shuttle.

Any recommendations?

I'm probably going to run windows server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking at the: Dell Studio Hybrid? http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=ddcwla2&c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&kc=productdetails~desktop-studio-hybrid its really small and should consume an amount of energy that one can live with.

And if you are going to run Windows Server on it and if I understand you correctly that you want to use it at home maybe Windows Home Server is just the thing for you and there are tons of great servers out there f.e. http://h41112.www4.hp.com/promo/mediasmart-server/de/de/
Sadly the Windows Home Server Pcs are not using a 64 bit processor so you couldn't install the next version of Windows Home Server on them.

Comment: Does the dell take 8 gigs?

Comment: Sorry only 4 GB. The problem is 8 GB and a small motherboard don't fit to well together at the moment its just to much heat that gets exposed.

Comment: Note that Windows Home Server isn't meant for interactive console usage; it's a NAS system.

Answer (score 0):

Overall small, or small in one specific dimensions?  Poweredge 1U units are short but deep and wide.

Otherwise just look into any mini-ATX or ATX board with x64 support and put it in a case of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

Might not fit your bill but what about an iMac? decent enough 64-bit processor, 8GB memory, nice screen, pretty - runs OSX, Windows, Linux all at the same time. Just a thought anyway.

Comment: I've got an iMac here and I love it as a desktop machine, but I don't think it would work for me as a server due to its lack of extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a Dell Studio Slim Desktop 540s on Dell Outlet. It's a mini tower form factor. A little bigger than a shuttle.

4 expansion slots
4 RAM slots
8GB RAM max
2 internal drive bays
1 5" external bay
1 3" external bay
built-in video

seems like a reasonable choice for a low-end, compact server with expandability